# shared memory allocator, without fixed shared segment size, lockable by multiple processes

Tags: memory-management, malloc, ipc, shared-memory

I need to have a malloc-like interface that allows to allocate blocks of memory in a shared segment. I don't want to set the size of this segment statically, the allocator should be able to manage growth as needed. The locking must be not only among threads of a single process, but system-wide: many processes might try to allocate blocks in the pool concurrently.

Is there a ready made library that can do this? I've found `libmm`, but it doesn't seem to allow interprocess locking, and I am a bit worried that it looks a abandoned, last update was on 2006.

Comment: [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) has such an allocator for its shared memory pool, but it's buried deep into the source code and might not be easily extactable into a standalone code.